# parse array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 

[3] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 

[6] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[7] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[8] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 
)
```

How can I split it base on id key and create one array for each id ?

Best Regards
Artam

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the answer to your question...

```
<?php
$payload = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 

[3] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 

[6] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[7] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[8] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 
)

// creates "separate" variables for entries named $payload_0, $payload_1, ...
foreach ($payload as $key=>$value) {
  $innerName = sprintf('payload_%s', $key);
  $$innerName = $value; 
}

// test output to make the conversion clear: 
var_dump($payload_4);
```

...which would make very little sense.

This only makes things more complex and doubles memory usage. You could just as well use the inner arrays in a direct manner as `$payload[4]` for example.

So the question is: *why* do you want to do such thing? For what purpose?

*Side note: the code above does not work, since I just copied your specified array notation which is invalid php code. But you should get the idea...*

---

Considering your comment below I'd say this is more likely what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$payload = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 

[3] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 2 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 

[6] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => RF [grpid] => 1 [value] => 1.40 ) 
[7] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => BP [grpid] => 2 [value] => 1.90 ) 
[8] => Array ( [id] => 3 [grpname] => DSH [grpid] => 3 [value] => 2.46 ) 
)

// iterate over the payload array and do whatever you want to do with the entries: 
foreach ($payload as $key=>$value) {
    // here output the inner array however you want to
    // $value now _is_ the inner value in each iteration of the loop
}
```

Comment: What I want is to built a table and print the array result in one single row for each distinct array[id].

Comment: I added some variant to the question which is probably more like what you are looking for...

Comment: Hello Arkascha thank you for your support but how can I create three array based on id key. Thanks in advance.